# Setting a web app as default program in Windows?

Tags: windows, website

I use [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) quite a bit for writing markdown files.  Is it possible in Windows 7 to associate a web app as default program for a given file type?

Comment: Try making an exe which accepts the file and opens it in StackEdit

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of, the closest thing would be opening the page by default and then importing your file from the page. And even that would be hard, as i think you can't pass any arguments to a program when its set as default, and you would have to make a program that launches your web page, and set that as default. You basically can't interact with a page from outside the browser. Short answer: No.